# Eliminating Variables in Semidefinite Programs Using Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose I have an SDP

\begin{align}\min_{X \in \mathbb{S}^{n}_{+}}&\quad f(X)\\\text{s.t.} &\quad X_{i,j} = c_{i,j} \quad \forall (i,j) \in I,\end{align}
where $I \subseteq [n] \times [n]$ and $f$ is convex on the set of positive semidefinite matrices. Are there any methods for solving SDPs which are able to simplify the problem by eliminating the constrained variables?

Comment: Cross posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40878/eliminating-variables-in-semidefinite-programs-using-equality-constraints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt you can eliminate the fixed variables in general but given some special structure it might be possible.

In [my paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-002-0349-3) I describe how to exploit fixed variables inside a primal-dual interior algorithm for conic quadratic optimization. However, I have not been able to generalize this idea to the semi-definite cone in a useful way.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about doing it in some particularly clever way? If you simply intend to solve the problem in the original dual space (i.e. seeing $X$ as a matrix parameterized by its elements and optimizing over those variables) it is just a matter of deriving a solution and basis for $Ax=c$ where $x$ are the elements parameterizing $X$, i.e., write $x = x_0 + Hz$ and then replace in $X$. In the modelling toolbox YALMIP, that would correspond to using the option **removeequalities** (which now more or less is obsolete as it most often would be best to let the solver deal with the equalities)

EDIT: In your case the solution and basis is trivial as all your conditions involve single elements, so I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do mean to focus on the situation where individual coordinates are equality constrained. Could you expand what you mean by "the solution and basis is trivial"?

Comment: You simply replace element $X_{ij}$ with $c_{ij}$, there is nothing more to do.

Comment: I don't follow. Doesn't fixing the elements complicate operations involving the positive semidefinite cone?

Comment: All depends on how you are solving the problem. A classical primal-dual solver for an SDP could work by interpreting the equalities from the primal/kernel side as constraints on the primal cone, or from the dual/image side by equalities on the dual variables or by simply deriving another image representation. This would only be an issue if you are using a very particular solution strategy which has to work with a very particular completely unconstrained representation of a cone.

Comment: Excellent. Could you point out some papers or codebases I could look at to understand this in more detail? I'm not familiar with the various representations of the PSD cone you describe.

Comment: A start perhaps to understand primal vs dual vs image vs kernel https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/automaticdualization